# SEGFAULT when trying to execute ELF64 mapped with mmap

Tags: c, low-level

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <elf.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd = open("a.out", O_RDONLY);
   
    struct stat file_info;
    if(fstat(fd, &file_info) < 0)
    {
        perror("fstat");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    void *mem = mmap(NULL, file_info.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    Elf64_Ehdr *elf_header = (Elf64_Ehdr *)mem;
    if (elf_header->e_ident[EI_MAG0] != ELFMAG0
        || elf_header->e_ident[EI_MAG1] != ELFMAG1
    || elf_header->e_ident[EI_MAG2] != ELFMAG2
        || elf_header->e_ident[EI_MAG3] != ELFMAG3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid ELF file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    Elf64_Shdr* section_header_table = (Elf64_Shdr*)((char*)mem + elf_header->e_shoff);
    Elf64_Shdr* section_header_string_table = &section_header_table[elf_header->e_shstrndx];
    char* section_header_string_table_mem = (char*)mem + section_header_string_table->sh_offset;

    Elf64_Shdr* text_section_header = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < elf_header->e_shnum)
    {
        char* section_name = section_header_string_table_mem + section_header_table[i].sh_name;
        if (strcmp(section_name, ".text") == 0)
        {
           text_section_header = &section_header_table[i];
           break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (text_section_header == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, ".text section not found\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    void* text_section_mem = (void*)((char*)mem + text_section_header->sh_offset);

    int (*text_section)(void) = (int (*)(void))text_section_mem;
    int result = text_section();

    printf("Result: %d\n", result);

    munmap(mem, file_info.st_size);
    close(fd);
}
```

The program segfaults when I try to execute the function at the end:
`int result = text_section();`

I checked that the pointer to the .text section is valid and did an objdump to check that the bytes were the same.
If it helps, the source code for the ELF I am trying to run is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int g_num = 6969;

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", g_num);
}
```

Both programs have been compiled with:
`gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`

Comment: Some speculation here. I'd guess your `a.out` is compiled to have it's .text section in some region A of the virtual memory and .data in some region B of the virtual memory. Yet you are mapping it in some plain region C. There could be also some relaxations enabled, so your `g_num` is expected to be accessed relatively to some global pointer, which is usually set up in the startup code, which you are not executing. You can run your program in a debugger and see what exactly is happening once you are trying to execute the function.

Comment: `mmap(NULL` so a position-independent executable? And `printf` calling something out of libc. I would expect to see a fair bit of code related to dynamic linking.

Comment: Starting a program is a bit more complicated than just finding the section and jumping into it. (it is possible if the section is self-sufficient and use only relative addressing (ie no global variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call a pointer to the *.text* section and expect this to execute a `printf`, instead you got a segmentation fault because what you are really calling is an entrypoint function, `_start`, which is invalid in this context, we can verify this by running `objdump -D a.out` :

```
section .text :
    
0000000000001040 <_start>:
    1040:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1044:   31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
    1046:   49 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%r9
    1049:   5e                      pop    %rsi
    104a:   48 89 e2                mov    %rsp,%rdx
    104d:   48 83 e4 f0             and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
    1051:   50                      push   %rax
    1052:   54                      push   %rsp
    
    [...]

0000000000001129 <main>:
    1129:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    112d:   55                      push   %rbp
    112e:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    1131:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
    1136:   5d                      pop    %rbp
    1137:   c3                      ret
```

To call `main()`, I suggest you just use his offset, here `main()` is located at offset +0x1129 :

```
int (*main_offset)(void) = (int (*)(void))((char *)mem + 0x1129);
int result = main_offset();
```

Still, calling `printf()` wont work and calling it will cause another segmentation fault because the address space of this mmaped binary has not been setup yet, libc is expected to be found at a certain address but It won't be there, you have to do the [loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loader_(computing)) job.

To get this running, you must only use locals functions.